# Squid, log request hostname

Tags: squid

I have a squid server that can be accessed from multiple subdomains. My question is: **is it possible to log the request's hostname (that is: hostname from the squid server) in the access log**?

So, for instance, if a user does a proxy request on "blahbla.example.com" or "blah.example.com", I want to see this specified in my logfile.

Can anybody help me with this? Thanks!

*P.S.: Log directive "<la" only logs the IP4/6 number. Not the actual hostname :(*

Answer (score -1):

Seems like the only way to accomplish this is using [squid log analyzer](http://www.squid-cache.org/Misc/log-analysis.html) and if you are not fun of using the web interface, it also have its raw logs on its docroot.

I would recommend [LigthSquid](http://lightsquid.sourceforge.net/) amongst all.